# Can't run Apache Zeppelin on windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, apache-zeppelin

I am using zeppelin on windows and I have the following issue. After executing the comand bin\zeppelin.cmd on command window and I see the message: "Done, zeppelin server has started" I browse at localhost:8080 and I get the following page:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /. Reason:
Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://
```

On the comand window there is this bug:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource class org.apache.zeppelin.server.Zeppel
inServer can not be instantiated due to InvocationTargetException
```

I have downloaded the binary package with all interpreters from zeppelin website (the latest) and I have the latest java installed. Any suggestions?